# How to tell JSHint to ignore all undefined variables in one file?

Tags: javascript, jshint

In Karma tests, there are a lot of global variables and functions, which JSHint complains about (it is integrated into my editor).

How can I tell JSHint to ignore all undefined variables in this one specific file? I would expect `/* jshint undef: false */` to turn off these warning, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The correct way to tell JSHint about globals is to use the `globals` directive. For example:

```
/*globals globalFunction, anotherGlobal, oneMore */
```

This will prevent "{a} is not defined" warnings when JSHint encounters any of the listed identifiers.

Alternatively, if you really want to ignore *all* "not defined" warnings in that file, and you're using JSHint 1.0.0 or above, you can simply turn off that specific warning:

```
/*jshint -W117 */
```

Comment: Thank you, but where did you find out about this? The [docs](http://www.jshint.com/docs/) don't mention command line args, and `jshint --help` expects me to know the name of the arg that I need help with.

Comment: @DanRoss - I think I found out about it from reading the source. I've done a lot of digging in the JSHint source while building http://jslinterrors.com, which may be of use to you.

Answer (score 9):

Just add this rule in your .jshintrc file.

```
"-W117": true
```

This will ignore all the warnings which say, '* is not defined.'

Comment: But then you have problems with variables which should be defined, but you made a syntax error. I wouldn't turn off this warning.

Comment: Better to do what @JamesAllardice suggests above, and just place it in the file where it is causing problems.

Answer (score 8):

Ran into this problem using jshint this afternoon.
This following fix worked for me.
Instead of using "globals", try using "predef".
For example:

```
{
  /*
   * RELAXING OPTIONS
   * =================
   */

  // Suppress warnings about == null comparisons.
  "eqnull": true,

  "predef" : ["describe", "expect", "it", "inject", "beforeEach", "angular"]
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I've found myself using `jshint ignore:line` as a way of addressing this need:

> var unusedVar; // jshint ignore:line

This allows jshint to continue its useful checking for this condition but where there are explicit reasons to ignore a specific declaration than adding this both addresses the issue and does it in a way that is immediately apparent to anyone looking at the code.

A good example (at least for me), is when using ES6's destructuring to illicit a set of shortcuts that you may or may not use all the time. In Ember, I often use many of the methods that hang off of it such as `typeOf` and `computed`. Rather than always referring to `Ember.computed` it's far nicer to just refer to `computed` and have something like the following at the top of all my Ember objects:

```
 const { computed, $, A, run, on, typeOf, debug, get, set } = Ember;    // jshint ignore:line
```