# Why is angular not declared?

Tags: angularjs

I am learning AngularJS and trying to do my first app where I count the number of characters left in the message text area. However, when I have

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
                    var app = angular.module("myContactApp", []);
                    app.controller("nmContactCtrl", function ($scope) {
                        console.log("In nmContactCtrl");
                        $scope.message = "";
                        $scope.charactersLeft = function () {
                            return 200 - $scope.userMessage.length;
                        };
                    });
</script>
```

the "angular.module" gives error in "var app = angular.module("myContactApp", []);" saying "The global variable angular is not declared". I have the minified angular.js in the script. Not sure why this showing the error.

Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Did you also include jquery before angular?

Comment: @Venice jQuery is not a prerequisite for angular.

Comment: @NeilS ah, good one. I didn't realize it fell back to jQLite if jQuery was not present. Aside from your questions, I do see he doesn't have a quote at the start of his src attribute.

Comment: Sorry, i missed the quotation mark here. I have it on my actual file. Not sure why angular is not declared.

Comment: There must be something else wrong or preventing the script from being loaded. Perhaps posting the entire contents of your html file would be helpful.

Comment: Neil, the script gets loaded but I get the "angular not declared" message in the editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a quotation mark.

```
<script src="http
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
                    var app = angular.module("myContactApp", []);
                    app.controller("nmContactCtrl", function ($scope) {
                        console.log("In nmContactCtrl");
                        $scope.message = "";
                        $scope.charactersLeft = function () {
                            return 200 - $scope.userMessage.length;
                        };
                    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

There are no errors here if I run this locally.

Comment: Sorry, i missed the quotation mark here. I have it on my actual file. Not sure why angular is not declared.

Comment: Even though message gets printed in the console, I still get "The global variable angular is not declared" in the editor. Not sure why...Do we need to declare it? I thought it was taken care by angularJS.

Comment: what editor are you referring to? Are you talking about your IDE?

Comment: yes Neil. I have eclipse IDE. And it gives the yellow line telling that angular is not declared.

Comment: OK, this is a feature of Eclipse and not an actual problem with your code. Eclipse does not send a http request and load the angular library, so it is not able to recognize angular as a declared variable. You can declare global variables in your files using the  answer from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359232/how-to-tell-jshint-to-ignore-all-undefined-variables-in-one-file

Comment: Thanks Neil for telling that it is Eclipse problem and not my code. I will look  into the solution that you linked too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a 'https' site? Because when I tried to repeat this on jsfiddle I got this error because there was also another one: "The page was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script"

So, if you use https then you should load AngularJS over https too:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">
```